# Как найти самых взрослых людей в каждом городе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из этого дата фрейма получить максимальный возраст для каждого города?

```py
df['age'].max()
```

выводит максимальное значение возраста среди всей таблицы.

Comment: Это ведь делается точно так же, как в `SQL`. Нужно просто знать общие принципы. Конкретика написана в ответе, но принципы знать надо. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.groupby('city')['age'].max()
```